# How to configure SenderCompId for quickfix auto failover configuration?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

In QuickFix/J there is configuration for auto failover for initiator like below:

```
SocketConnectHost=localhost1
SocketConnectPort=9876
SocketConnectHost1=localhost2
SocketConnectPort1=9877
```

In above alternate ip or port can be provided like SocketConnectHost**n** and SocketConnectPort**n**. But above is a session failover mechanism since SenderCompID and TargetCompID are same.

Is there a way by which I can configure the SenderCompID along with socketConnect host and port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes you simply setup under a new session, kind of like so:

```
[default]
ReconnectInterval=5
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=60
ReconnectInterval=60
ResetOnLogon=Y
DataDictionary=FIX.4.4.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=Sender1
TargetCompID=Target1
SocketConnectPort=1201
SocketConnectHost=1.2.3.4
FileStorePath=store1
FileLogPath=log1
ConnectionType=initiator

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=Sender2
TargetCompID=Target2
SocketConnectPort=1202
SocketConnectHost=1.2.3.5
FileStorePath=store2
FileLogPath=log2
ConnectionType=initiator

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=Sender3
TargetCompID=Target3
SocketConnectPort=1203
SocketConnectHost=1.2.3.6
FileStorePath=store3
FileLogPath=log3
ConnectionType=initiator
```

Comment: When the second session will become active? How the 2nd session configuration will become active?

Comment: It becomes active at the same time as the 1st. I haven't exactly looked into [the code](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/4bcf552b8a25fe3724a94aee7d15c57a675b1f13/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/SocketInitiator.java) but basically the config file determines what sessions come online, then there's 1 thread to handle all messages on all sessions, with each having their own session id. That way you know who sent / received what message. Thus, for auto failover, you've already initiated the failover session on start up. The failover process is about how you switch messages to it.

Comment: Then again, for failover, if the 1st session drops it ought to produce an `onLogout()` event. Then you could simply use the `logon()` for that session again, or `logon()` for some failover session.